# Rotating between 21 positions counterclockwise?

Tags: arduino

I'm building an Arduino-based control system for a model railway turntable and I need to be able to rotate it clockwise or counterclockwise at will. I have 21 positions on the turntable, which I currently have numbered 0-20. I need to figure out how many "clicks" counterclockwise it will take to get to a given track number. How on earth can I go about finding this?

If there's a math-y way I can do it, that would be fantastic. I don't want to have an endless series of IF statements if I can avoid it.

Comment: Does it, or are you using a rotary encoder or stepper motor? Basically how is the Arduino detecting clicks. You could also place micro switches at the start and end of its travel and have a tab hit them, then your Arduino knows where the turntable is.

Comment: It's an existing turntable that uses a simple DC motor, and I am simply adding a small magnet to one of the gears with a hall effect sensor. Basically a magnet-based tachometer for the gear. I tested and found that this gear turns 5 times for every 1 track move of the turntable, so I can go from there in programming the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found a very simple, elegant way.

Let's take my turntable for example. 21 positions, numbered 0-20.

If we are at track 0, and we have 20 tracks total, and we want to go to track 16 counterclockwise, we could do:

```
moves = 0 + ((20 + 1) - 16)
```

This yields 5, meaning if we move the turntable counterclockwise 5 tracks, we end up at track 16.

Simple, elegant, and extends to fit an infinite number of possible positions.